# built in unix / linux command for recursive find and replace?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

Many people string together find and sed, or perl, or any number of other unix commands to find and replace across multiple files. But, there's a simple command that can do it for you without the hassle?

Edit: 
The Digital Ninja points out that it's rpl.

However this is not a built in command but, for debian based distros like Ubuntu you can simply install it with
    sudo apt-get install rpl

I would guess that it's available through most package managers in other *nix OSs.
OS X Users can download a binary at 
http://www.laffeycomputer.com/rpl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you are thinking of 'rpl' 
http://www.linux.org/apps/AppId_2684.html

Answer (score 1):

I think some variation of the following would work :

```
find . -name *.extension | perl -pi.bak -e "s/text_to_be_replaced/replacement/"
```

Comment: well, yes, and I alluded to that, but the point was to find a command that did it without the user having to string together various combinations of unix commands and perl, sed, or anything else.

Comment: also, it would be perl -pi -e (no .bak)

Comment: But you can always chain the commands yourself and put it on a simple shell script file.